# How to put a bar above a QwtPlot graph?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwt

Can I put a bar above a graph created with `QwtPlot` in **Qt** (**C++**)?

If yes, how can I do that? Any example?

The bar I want to put on the graph represents the day and night periods, and it looks like these:

[image]

Qwt 6.1.0

Qt 5.3.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the bar using a QFrame and painted it manually using the paintEvent function.